# snapcraft build issue: GLIBC wrong version

Tags: snap, packaging

Rebuilding package with new version after successfully build it last week this week I am having issues:

```
The GLIBC version of the targeted core is 2.23.
A newer libc will be required for the following files:

- ... /prime/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.7 (requires GLIBC 2.25)
- ... /prime/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfdisk.so.1.1.0 (requires GLIBC 2.25)
- ... /prime/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpatw.so.1.6.7 (requires GLIBC 2.25)
- .../prime/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.3.0 (requires GLIBC 2.26)
- .../prime/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.14.10 (requires GLIBC 2.25)
- ... /prime/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0.8.7 (requires GLIBC 2.25)

'libc6' is required inside the snap for this part to work properly.
Add it as a `stage-packages` entry for this part.
```

Please advise how do I update snap glibc version?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the problem, the issue was that I was trying to run $ snapcraft to build but when I used cleanbuild it worked and no errors.

```
$ snapcraft cleanbuild
```